# Populating an array into a TableView

Tags: arrays, uitableview, uitextview, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

In a tableView I have the following:

```
NSDictionary *cat = [category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
cell.textLabel.text = [cat valueForKey:@"reference"];
```

This populates the tableView with the content of the array from an XML file. 
There is another array “data” that prints out the content to the debug console and I want to populate another view with this content. But I am having lot of trouble populating the next view with the data array.

```
NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath-- Reference:%@: Verse:%@", [cat valueForKey:@"reference"], [cat valueForKey:@"data"]);
```

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method looks like this:

```
Verse *vvc = [[Verse alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerseView" bundle:nil];  vvc.verses = [[category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"verse"];  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vvc animated:YES];  
        [vvc release];  
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath of the next view I have the following:

```
NSDictionary *cat = [verses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
cell.textLabel.text = [cat valueForKey:@"data"];
```

What I would like is to have the “data” in a textView.

I don’t know what’s wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the data in a textview inside of the table cell or somewhere else on the layout of the application? You could always store it in a file and then read from that file somewhere else.